# new Chart() is not defined

Tags: javascript, html5, chart.js

Hola tengo un chart dentro del evento addEventListener y tengo un error con el new Chart me envia un mensaje el test indicando que no esta definido el metodo, alguno ha podido resolver este conflicto, tengo el siguiente script en html

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
    new Chart (ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ['Total Pokemones', 'Porcentaje ' + condition],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [dataPokemon.length, sizePokemon],
                backgroundColor: [
                    
                    
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    
                ],
                borderColor: [
                   
                    
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<div id="myChart"></div>
```

Comment: A mi me funciona bien tu codigo, solo te hace falta esto: `let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext("2d");`

Comment: si funciona, el problema es cuando voy a pasar el test el slint me indica que no existe new Chart

Comment: coloca tu js antes de cerrar el body

Comment: asi estan antes de cerrar el body

Comment: ¿Porqué llamas directamente a `new Chart()` sin realizar una asignación? Por ejemplo: `var chart = new Chart(...);`

Comment: lo realice asi con variable y sin variable, funciona pero el error es del test que no encuentra la libreria Chart

Answer (score 0):

Asegurate de que todas las variables que utilizas existen y están inicializadas y que tu elemento html con el id del chart es un canvas

```js
let condition = 100;
let dataPokemon = ["Abra", "pikachu"];
let sizePokemon = 50;
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
    new Chart (ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ['Total Pokemones', 'Porcentaje ' + condition],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [dataPokemon.length, sizePokemon],
                backgroundColor: [
                    
                    
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    
                ],
                borderColor: [
                   
                    
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: el chart esta en un archivo js, y en el html solo esta el script

Comment: En el html tienes que añadir un `<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>` que es donde se va a generar y mostrar el gráfico. También tienes que asegurarte que el script que llama a la librería del chart está por encima en tu código a la llamada a tu fichero JS y que en ese fichero JS esas variables que llamas `dataPokemon`, `sizePokemon` y `condition` existen y tienen algún valor.

Fíjate en el código que te he insertado como puedes darle a ejecutar y funciona, intenta replicarlo

Comment: te dejo el link de la pagina para que veas  que funciona pero el test no pasa https://nohestmm.github.io/SCL009-data-lovers/src/index.html

Comment: Cómo se debería abrir el chart?

Comment: en los filtro lo coloque al final